# 150 'no-follow' links to another site I own. Will I get a penalty?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have two websites. One website has 50 articles published and is doing quite well. In all the articles published, I have 2-3 links that go to a subdomain of that website. Now I just started a second fresh/new site, and I would like to replace all the links in the current articles on website 1, to website 2 (so not the subdomain, but the new/fresh site).

***Question:***

Is it okay to do this without getting a penalty? Just to be sure I am making all the links `no-follow`. Can I replace these 150'ish links all in one day, or should it be spread out over several days? Im quite new to this 'technical SEO'.

Thanks.

Comment: My first thought was, why do you have two separate sites? These two "sites" would seem to be intrinsically linked and would benefit from being on one hostname? What is it you are hoping to achieve here?

Comment: The first site was my very first site ever. More of a playground to see what works and what doesn't. This new site I am going to professionalize a bit more. In the future I might make it one site, but for now I'll just make 2. Is it okay for me to link to the new site with `no-follow` links?

Answer (score 1):

No you won't get penalty for making no follow links.
While making no follow you are saying to google : I don't trust this website.

Even if you have done normal link "do follow"'s links (don't add this attribute it doesn't exist, it's just to explain), you won't get penalty.

if you're not sure, explain google using schema.org that you're the same owner of those 2 website and everything will be ok.

just an example : when a company add a blog in a subdomain, with the footer on the main domain, the subdomain is linked sitewide, the blog won't get penalty.

Stop being afraid by what google say about links.